# Tor not working after update to Tor 0.2.6.9

Tags: onion-services

Today I updated Tor to version 0.2.6.9. As it was updating, I got an error like "bind to address failed". After that, I can't start, stop or anything..

This is installed on a server running centos and Tor is installed via the Tor Project official repository.

[image]

I tried re-installing but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Are there any relating entries in the logfile?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply here is my tor.log file http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=YkP2Qnrh

netstat shows the port is not open but when i try to start it says tor is already running :S

Comment: If the port is not open, Tor is still running. Can you force kill the tor service. ps aux | grep "tor" to find the PID (which should be 4381). Then kill {PID}.